# How to add new events on double click for fullcalendar plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am using [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) plugin to schedule meetings and appointments.

I can retrieve all the events associated with Day/Month/Week. Now, I want to add double click event on empty cells (where there are no appointment scheduled).

I tried using dayRender, but it's not reliable because its only working for few cells not all. I tried eventRender, which works fine for all those cells who have events associated.

Right now I am using double click event of jQuery, as below:

```
    $(CALENDAR.Calendar).undelegate("dblclick").delegate("td", "dblclick", function () {        
    if (!isEventsLoaded) {
        common.notificationMessage("Please sit back we are loading calendar events.", 0);
        return false;
    }
    alreadyClicked = true;
    var hasEventAssigned = $(this).find("a").attr('href')
    var isFutureMonth = $(this).hasClass("fc-other-month")
    if (alreadyClicked && hasEventAssigned == undefined && !isFutureMonth) {
        openEditSALPopUp();
        alreadyClicked = false;
    }
    return false;
});
```

It works fine, it opens up the modal popup to add a new calendar or appointment, but i cannot find the date/time for which this appointment needs to be scheduled.

Please help me getting over this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around for a while and my best solution was:

- Use the dayClick callback of fullcalendar to get the moment of a       single click on an unoccupied slot
- Remember the moment of the slot clicked
- If the mouse moves, forget the moment
- Bind a dblClick event handler to the calendar div. When it fires, check if there is a remembered moment and do something with it.

Code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    dayClick: dayClickCallback,
    ...
});

var slotMoment;

function dayClickCallback(date){
    slotMoment = date;
    $("#calendar").on("mousemove", forgetSlot);
}

function forgetSlot(){
    slotMoment = null;
    $("#calendar").off("mousemove", forgetSlot);
}

$("#calendar").dblclick(function() {
    if(slotMoment){
        console.log(slotMoment); //do something with the moment
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. I did try to implement this and it worked, checked only events. Current code allows double click on those cells which has already events assigned, which is not the case in my current situation. I only want to perform double click to those cells which are empty, no event assigned.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you describe as an empty cell. Double clicking on an event won't return a moment object. I created a jsfiddle of the code we agree almost works (http://jsfiddle.net/scottysmalls/xswhfgqy/) Can you describe or maybe show a screenshot of where it fails?

Comment: Thank you, i have implemented the logic as per your snippet and that helped me. FYI, Empty cells means, those sections on the calendar which are not assigned with any events.

Comment: what to do the same for occupied slot?